# How can I send an email using python logging's SMTPHandler and SSL

Tags: python, ssl, flask, error-logging, smtplib

I'm developing a flask app in which I'd like to send error level logging to an email address. I tried setting up the typical error handler:

```
mail_handler = SMTPHandler(mailhost=(app.config['MAIL_SERVER'], app.config['MAIL_PORT']),
                           fromaddr=app.config['MAIL_FROM_EMAIL'],
                           toaddrs=['me@my_address.com'],
                           subject='The server died. That sucks... :(',
                           credentials=(app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'], app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']))
```

Note the configuration values are as set up using [flask-mail](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/), with `MAIL_USE_SSL=True` and `MAIL_PORT=465`.

However, upon invoking an error (on purpose during testing) I get socket timeout errors - other than the port, I can't see how to tell the handler to use SSL. There is a `secure=()` parameter that can be passed (see [the SMTPHandler docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#smtphandler)) but that specifies us of TLS, not SSL.

Any clues how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**EDIT - see bottom of post for more up-to-date, code**

Figured it out with thanks to [Ned Deily](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/769367) pointing out that smtplib (which sits under SMTPHandler) requires special treatment. I also found [this post](http://mynthon.net/howto/-/python/python%20-%20logging.SMTPHandler-how-to-use-gmail-smtp-server.txt) demonstrating how to do that, by overloading the SMTPHandler (in that case to fix a TLS problem).

Using `smtplib.SMTP_SSL` ([see smtplib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL)), rather than the straightforward `smtplib.SMTP`, I was able to get the whole system working. This is the utils/logs.py file I use to set up the handlers (which should be a nice example of file, as well as email, handlers):

```
from your.application.file import app

import smtplib
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler, SMTPHandler


# Provide a class to allow SSL (Not TLS) connection for mail handlers by overloading the emit() method
class SSLSMTPHandler(SMTPHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        """
        Emit a record.
        """
        try:
            port = self.mailport
            if not port:
                port = smtplib.SMTP_PORT
            smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.mailhost, port)
            msg = self.format(record)
            if self.username:
                smtp.login(self.username, self.password)
            smtp.sendmail(self.fromaddr, self.toaddrs, msg)
            smtp.quit()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except:
            self.handleError(record)


# Create file handler for error/warning/info/debug logs
file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/app.log', maxBytes=1*1024*1024, backupCount=100)

# Apply format to the log messages
formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] |  %(levelname)s | {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d} | %(message)s")
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# Set the level according to whether we're debugging or not
if app.debug:
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
else:
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARN)

# Create equivalent mail handler
mail_handler = SSLSMTPHandler(mailhost=(app.config['MAIL_SERVER'], app.config['MAIL_PORT']),
                           fromaddr=app.config['MAIL_FROM_EMAIL'],
                           toaddrs='my@emailaddress.com',
                           subject='Your app died. Sad times...',
                           credentials=(app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'], app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']))

# Set the email format
mail_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('''
Message type:       %(levelname)s
Location:           %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d
Module:             %(module)s
Function:           %(funcName)s
Time:               %(asctime)s

Message:

%(message)s
'''))

# Only email errors, not warnings
mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

This is registered in my application file with:

```
# Register the handlers against all the loggers we have in play
# This is done after app configuration and SQLAlchemy initialisation, 
# drop the sqlalchemy if not using - I thought a full example would be helpful.
import logging
from .utils.logs import mail_handler, file_handler
loggers = [app.logger, logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy'), logging.getLogger('werkzeug')]
for logger in loggers:
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    # Note - I added a boolean configuration parameter, MAIL_ON_ERROR, 
    # to allow direct control over whether to email on errors. 
    # You may wish to use 'if not app.debug' instead.
    if app.config['MAIL_ON_ERROR']:
        logger.addHandler(mail_handler)
```

**EDIT:**

Commenter @EduGord has had trouble emitting the record correctly. 
Digging deeper, the base SMTPHandler class is sending messages differently than it was 3+ years ago.

This updated `emit()` method should get the message to format correctly:

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
import email.utils
class SSLSMTPHandler(SMTPHandler):

    def emit(self, record):
        """
        Emit a record.
        """
        try:
            port = self.mailport
            if not port:
                port = smtplib.SMTP_PORT
            smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.mailhost, port)
            msg = EmailMessage()
            msg['From'] = self.fromaddr
            msg['To'] = ','.join(self.toaddrs)
            msg['Subject'] = self.getSubject(record)
            msg['Date'] = email.utils.localtime()
            msg.set_content(self.format(record))
            if self.username:
                smtp.login(self.username, self.password)
            smtp.send_message(msg, self.fromaddr, self.toaddrs)
            smtp.quit()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except:
            self.handleError(record)
```

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the emails were not receiving a subject.
But then, when replacing msg in SSLSMTPHandler.emit with

msg = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(self.subject,  self.format(record))

It worked pretty fine

Comment: For my 2c; formatting the record within the SMTPHandler violates separation of concerns... the record should already have been formatted correctly by the time it reaches emit(). Are you sure you were passing the subject keyword correctly?

Comment: I am @thclark : SSLSMTPHandler([...]subject='Falha em meuApp',[...]) . Plus, I also had to modify smtp.sendmail(self.fromaddr, self.toaddrs, msg.encode("iso-8859-1")) to allow special characters from my mother language (PT-BR).

Comment: @EduGord can you have a try of the solution I've posted and see if it works please?

Comment: I've tested your solution. Seems like you forgot to declare msg. I set msg = EmailMessage() and it's working properly now. Thank you again!

Comment: Is subclassing SMTPHandler necessary, why wouldn't you just subclass logging.Handler and create your custom handler like that as you are doing all the smtp work already?