# Logging Python SMTPHandler into emails for CLI SMTP Server

Tags: python, smtp

The goal is to complete a Flask tutorial where it is used logging.handler.SMTPHandler to send logs to SMTP debugging server from Python.

The Python server is run under windows cli, open a new windows CLI as admin and run:
`python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025`

To test it the following code should work:

```
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

smtpHandler = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(
    mailhost = ("localhost",8025),
    fromaddr = "alerts@localhost",
    toaddrs = "geo555@localhost",
    subject = "alert!"
)

smtpHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.debug("here is the test logging for u.")
```

Have tried so far and no message is appearing in the debuggingserver:

- https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-vii-error-handling
  Does not send any output to debugging server.
- [How can I send an email using python logging's SMTPHandler and SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937461/how-can-i-send-an-email-using-python-loggings-smtphandler-and-ssl) is not explicitly using the debugging server and it did not work.

What can be a very simple example that can do this, otherwise using debugging to file which also works.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to add the stmpHandler to the logger: `logger.addHandler(smtpHandler)`

Below is a full working code:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")

sender = "emailuser@localhost"
pwd = "pass123"

smtpHandler = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(
    mailhost=("localhost", 25),
    fromaddr="noreply@example.com",
    toaddrs="user@email.com",
    subject="alert!",
    credentials=(sender, pwd),
)

smtpHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# add this line
logger.addHandler(smtpHandler)

logger.debug("here is the test logging for u.")
```